# How to update list on main form of c# application

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, thread-safety

I have a C# application that has a class called *MainView* for the main form which contains a reference to an instance of the *Connection* class. The *Connection* class has a SerialPort object which means I have a method in the *Connection* class called *dataReceivedHandler()* that runs everytime data is received.

I want to add this received data to a list on the *MainView* form, however I cannot do this inside the dataReceivedHandler() method as I get a cross thread error.

What is the best way to overcome this in C#? Do I need to create a delegate in the *MainView* class. I'm not sure of how this should be structured.

Edit:

Note: the code has been modified to reflect my final solution.

Connection Class:

```
public class Connection{

    // delegate and event for updating the datacollection in parent class
    public delegate void UpdateDataCollectionDelegate(Datum newDatum);
    public event UpdateDataCollectionDelegate UpdateDataCollectionEvent;

    // method is called everytime the SerialPort.DataReceived event occurs
    // and runs in a separate thread.
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = "";
            try
            {
                indata = sp.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data read timed out.");
            }
            MessageBox.Show(indata, "Raw Input"); 
            // convert raw bytes to comma delimited string
            String delimitedData = Data.RawData.convertRawToString(indata.ToCharArray());
            //print delimited data to messagebox
            MessageBox.Show("Received Data: \n" + delimitedData);
            // store the data in an object that represents a single result
            Data.Datum newDatum = new Data.Datum(delimitedData);

            UpdateDataCollectionEvent(newDatum);
   }
}
```

MainView Class:

```
public partial class MainView : Form{
    private Connection serialCon;
    // I want to update this list from the serialCon object
    private BindingList<Datum> dataCollection;

    public MainView(){
        serialCon = new Connection();
        // Point the serial connections update data collection event to the update data collection method in this class.
        serialCon.UpdateDataCollectionEvent += updateDataCollection;
    }

   private void updateDataCollection(Datum newDatum) {
        Action<Datum> del = addToDataCollection;
        this.BeginInvoke(del, newDatum);
    }

   private void addToDataCollection(Datum newDatum) {
        dataCollection.Add(newDatum);
    }
}
```

Comment: could u post some code please

Comment: Not sure without seeing code, but you could just spin off a `backgroundworker` and `invoke` the changes you wish to make.

Comment: Look up `BeginInvoke` that should solve your problem.

Comment: You have `private BindingList<Datum> dataCollection;`... But it is marked as `private` so how can other classes access it? Are you sure you have copied it correctly?

Comment: @Belogix Sorry I didn't post all the code. I passed a reference to the dataCollection object to the connection object so it has access to it.

Comment: Should I have a delegate and a method on the MainView form for Invoke or BeginInvoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  fact the serial port will have his it's own thread and when you try to update UI you will get a `CrossThreadException`.

Take a look at this [`link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx) to understand more on How to make Thread-Safe calls to windows forms controls.

You can simply avoid this by doing trying the following code:

```
 private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Action<Datum> del = UpdateMyCollection;  
            this.BeginInvoke(del,Data.Datum); 

        }
         void  UpdateMyCollection(Datum newDatum)
         {
             _dataCollection.Add(newDatum);
         }
```

Comment: So when you have *Action<Datum> del = UpdateMyCollection;* Are you creating a delegate and pointing it to the UpdateMyCollection method?

Comment: yes that's right  the method  UpdateMyCollection will be invoked on  the UI to avoid the CrossThreadException

Comment: Are you suggesting that the above code be inserted into the MainView form class? If so, how will it get the newDatum object?

Comment: I used similar code on my *MainView* form but I had to trigger it by creating an event called in the *Connection* class.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to reflect my solution.

Comment: So what's the issue you are facing

Comment: I don't have an issue now, I have a working solution. Thank you for your help!